# How two or more consecutive zeros(off) or one (on) in digital circuits are recognized?

Tags: digital-logic, binary

So digital circuits work by using two states either on or off , and i was wondering how two consecutive bits of zero(or one) be identified? is there like a timing circuit or anything like that?

Comment: You need to define how the bit is to be transmitted before you can try to decode bits. Are they in parallel? Or series? Do they have a synchronous clock, or use asynchronous start pulse? Because it all depends. Just like using a flashlight to send data, you need some sort of protocol what the light being on or off mean, or perhaps use a code like Morse code to send data on the wire like you would with a flashlight.

Comment: I am talking about series

Comment: to use a walkie talkie example: sometimes there's a beep before each message (a "clock" pulse on another line, really should be called a "next" pulse") ex I2C, or it reads a number off every 5 seconds (ex: I2S).

Comment: The maximum number of on off states is a binary exponent 2^N

Comment: In case of digital logic circuits, they always have a clock/edge input pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest to understand is a serial connection like RS232. It works as follows:

- A bit rate is agreed. Typically this will be 9600 bits per second but can vary from 300 to 115000 or so.
- A character length is agreed. Typically this is 7 or 8 bits.
- The line default is agreed. This is typically 0 or off.
- The transmission (TX) of a character is initiated with a start bit - typically a '1'. This signals to the receiver (RX) to start its internal timer.
- The 7 or 8 bits of data are then transmitted serially at the set bit rate.
- The transmission ends with a stop bit which compliments the start bit - so a '0'. This ensures that the next start bit can be detected.
- The system relies on having clocks at each end that can stay reasonably will in sync for the duration of one character transmission. They will resync at the transmission of the next start bit.

```
         __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __             __ __ __
 _______|  |__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__,________|  |__|__|__
         1   Data ................   0   idle   1  data ...
```

Note that because the clocks can drift a little that the receiver on detecting the start bit will wait 1.5 bits and try to measure on the mid-point of each data bit. This way if the clocks drift relative to each other the reading should still be done within the bit period without error.

This system has the advantage of only needing one signal wire and return for a one-directional transmission.

---

Within a chip or on a circuit board the cost of cabling is not a factor so an internal clock signal can be used alongside the data signal. Now the devices are exactly synchronised and a simpler shift-register approach can be used to transmit the data.

Comment: Actually RS232 only defines the electrical interface for logic levels, not what protocol is used to send data, even though in practice an UART is used to use asynchronous start/stop framing. However it idles at logic 1, start bit is logic 0, and stop bit is logic 1, but after RS232 level translation, logic 1 on wire is negative and logic 0 is positive.

Answer (score 0):

A basic AND or OR digital gate will respond to changes at its inputs as fast as its internal circuitry permits. If you want it to respond only at certain times, then, as you surmised, timing circuits are required. A simple example is a D flip-flop which has one data input and one clock input. The output can only change state when the clock goes high. Thus even if the input is constantly changing state, going from zero to one and back, the flip flop only cares what the state is when the clock goes high (this is simplified since in real flip flops the input state must stay steady for a time before the clock goes high which is called the set-up time).

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong aren't the bits inputed into the gets in parallel?so when the bits flow in series it requires a clock circuit?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the bits are in series or parallel.  You still need some sort of timing circuit if you only want to consider the values of the bits at distinct times which is usually the case.. You can use multiple clock periods to feed a signal into one flip-flop for serial data or use one clock signal to simultaneously feed a parallel signal into multiple flip=flops, one for each parallel bit.

Comment: What about cds or  hard disks are there any timing track or something

Comment: @Nobody no timing track. The data is coded in a way to include timing information. CDs use EFM and who knows what coding hard disks use these days, but at least they have used MFM coding and RLL coding.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a circuit that will output 1 when 2 zeros will occur in sequence

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMkE7V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

2 D flip flops that you see is making a 2 bit serial-in-parallel-out shit register.
If value at `REG1 D` is some value at time \$t_n\$ then value at `REG1 Q` will have value of time \$t_{n-1}\$ and so the value of `REG2 Q` will have value of time \$t_{n-2}\$.

However, this could be implemented just using 1 D Flip Flop but it is good to latch the value first and then do rest of processing.